# Trying to call methods based on user input and then inside of an IF statement call further input options

Tags: java

I am designing a catering UI for a bootcamp project and need to call these methods

```
    package com.techelevator.view;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.techelevator.item.Appetizer;
import com.techelevator.item.Beverage;
import com.techelevator.item.Dessert;
import com.techelevator.item.Entree;
import com.techelevator.item.Item;
import com.techelevator.readandwrite.*;
import com.techelevator.transaction.FinalCart;
import com.techelevator.transaction.UserAccount;
import com.techelevator.*;


    /*
     * This is the only class that should have any usage of System.out or System.in
     */
    public class Menu {
        
        private  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        
        ObjectConverter objectConverter = new ObjectConverter();
        CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
        
        UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount(0);
        FinalCart finalCart = new FinalCart();
        Item item = new Item(null, null, null);
        
        
        public String mainMenuDispay() {
            
            System.out.println( " Main Menu ");
            System.out.println(" ================================================= ");      
            System.out.println(" 1) Display Catering Items " );
            System.out.println(" 2) Order " );
            System.out.println(" 3) Quit " );
            return in.nextLine();
        }
    
            
        public String placeOrderScreen() {
        
            System.out.println(" Order ");
            System.out.println(" ================================================== ");
            System.out.println(" 1) Add Funds ");
            System.out.println(" 2) Make a selection ");
            System.out.println(" 3) Checkout ");
            System.out.println(" Your Account Balance is $" + userAccount.getAccountBalance()) ;
        
            String userChoice = in.nextLine();
            
            if (userChoice.equals("1")) {
                return askForUserDeposit();
            }
             if (userChoice.equals("2")) {
                 return placeOrderSelection();  
            }
             if (userChoice.equals("3")) {
                return "";//checkout.checkoutmethod;
            } return "";
        }
        
        
        public String placeOrderSelection() {
            String userInput = ""; 
            userInput = in.nextLine();
            
            Map<String, Item> newMapofItems = new LinkedHashMap<String, Item>();
            newMapofItems = objectConverter.mapMaker();
    
            System.out.println(" Order ");
            System.out.println(" ================================================== ");
            System.out.println(" 1) Make a selection ");
            
            if (newMapofItems.containsKey(userInput)) {
                return placeOrderQuantity();
                
            } System.out.println("This Is not a valid selection. Please select another item");
                return placeOrderSelection();   
        }
            
            
            
    
        
            
        
    
            
        public String placeOrderQuantity() {
            Map <String,Item>newMapofItems = objectConverter.mapMaker();
            String userInput = in.nextLine();
            int userInputQuantityAsInt = 0;
            userInputQuantityAsInt = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            
            System.out.println(" ================================================== ");
            System.out.println(" 2) select quantity ");
            
            if(userInputQuantityAsInt < item.getItemQuantity()) {
                finalCart.addItem(newMapofItems.get(userInput), userInputQuantityAsInt );
                System.out.print("Your item was added to your cart. Make another selection");
                System.out.println();
            } 
            if (userInputQuantityAsInt > item.getItemQuantity()) {
                System.out.println("Sorry only" + item.getItemQuantity() + "left! Please select again");
            
            } return placeOrderSelection();
        }
        
        public String askForUserDeposit () {
            String userDeposit = in.nextLine();
            Double deposit = Double.valueOf(userDeposit);
    
            System.out.println("Make a deposit");
            System.out.println("==============================");
            System.out.println("Enter amount of $ to add");
                
            
                if (deposit + userAccount.getAccountBalance() > 5000) {
                    System.out.println("Account balance cannot exceed $5000");
                } if(deposit + userAccount.getAccountBalance() < 5000) {
                    userAccount.addMoneyToAccount(deposit);
                    System.out.println("Thanks for your deposit!");
                } return placeOrderScreen();
        }
```

Here in the main method based on the choice the user inputs in the console

```
    package com.techelevator;

import java.util.List;



import com.techelevator.readandwrite.CsvReader;
import com.techelevator.readandwrite.ObjectConverter;
import com.techelevator.view.Menu;

    /*
     * This class should control the workflow of the application, but not do any other work
     * 
     * The menu class should communicate with the user, but do no other work
     * 
     * The work of the Catering System should be in other classes that you build and 
     * call from here. 
     */
    public class CateringSystemCLI {
        
        /*
         * The menu class is instantiated in the main() method at the bottom of this file.  
         * It is the only class instantiated in the starter code.  
         * You will need to instantiate all other classes using the new keyword before you can use them.
         * 
         * Remember every class and data structure is a data types and can be passed as arguments to methods or constructors.
         */
        private Menu menu;
        private CsvReader csvreader;
        private ObjectConverter objectConverter;
        private int choice = 0;
        
    
        /*
         * Constructor for listOfLines
         */
        
    
        public CateringSystemCLI(Menu menu, CsvReader csvreader) {
            this.csvreader = csvreader;
            this.menu = menu;
        }
        
        
    
        /*
         * Your application starts here
        
         */
        
        
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                
                /*
                Display the Starting Menu and get the users choice
                
                IF the User Choice is Display Vending Machine Items, 
                    THEN display vending machine items
                ELSE IF the User's Choice is Purchase,
                    THEN go to the purchase menu
                */
                    
                
                
    
                String choice = menu.mainMenuDispay();
    
                if (choice.equals("1")) {
                    csvreader.getItemsFromFilePrint(); 
                    System.out.println();
                    choice = menu.mainMenuDispay(); 
                }
                
                 if (choice.equals("2") ) {
                    choice = menu.placeOrderScreen();
                    else if (choice.equals("1")); {
                        choice = menu.askForUserDeposit();
                        
                    }
                     if (choice.equals("2")) {
                        choice = menu.placeOrderSelection();
                    }
                    else if (choice.equals("3")) {
                        choice = "";//menu.checkoutMenu
                    }
                }   
                
                if (choice.equals("3")); {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Thanks for Shopping");
                    break;  
                }
            
        }
```

How would I go about that? once i get through the first set of IF statements I cannot figure out how to call the options from that class and get the possible choices based on what the User inputs next

Comment: I see you have ```else``` before an ```if``` inside an ```if (choice.equals("2") )```! surely that code does not compile.

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside loop:

```
            String choice = menu.mainMenuDispay();

            if (choice.equals("1")) {
                csvreader.getItemsFromFilePrint(); 
                System.out.println(); 
            }
            
             else if (choice.equals("2")) {
                menu.placeOrderScreen();
                
            }   
            
            else if (choice.equals("3")); {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Thanks for Shopping");
                break;  
            }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.